# How do I crop an svg file with too much whitespace in Inkscape?

Tags: svg, inkscape

I have a SVG-file that has too much white space around it.

How do I get rid of this?

In tools like Photoshop, there's usually an easy cropping tool or some canvas resizing button under the Edit menu.

Comment: This might fare better on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ rather than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Document Properties -> Resize page to content`

Credit: https://inkscape.org/forums/questions/cropping-an-svg-file/